# Substitution method to prove recursion running time

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, substitution

I am working on these three recursion funtion to prove a big-O. I tried to use substitution method. But, I have no clue to guess a proper upper bound.

`(a) T(n) = T(n − 2q − 1) + T(3q/2) + T(q/2) + Θ(1)
(b) T(n) = T(n − q − 1) + T(n/2 − q) + Θ(n)
(c) T(n) = T(n − q − 1) + T(3q) + Θ(n)`

where q is constant from 0 to n/4.

Can some one give me some suggestion?

Comment: How can a constant (`q`) be bound to `n`?

Answer (score 0):

> T(n) = (a)+(b)-(c)
>
> T(n) = T(n-2q-1) + T(3q/2) + T(q/2) + Θ(1) + T(n/2-q) - T(3q)
>
> T(n) = T(n-2q-1) + T(n/2-q) + T(3q/2) + T(q/2) - T(3q) + Θ(1)

at this point i would try to build recursion tree and see how it behaves.

Comment: actually there are three qurstions.  They are not together.

Comment: maybe you should build a recursion tree and see a pattern in the increasing levels.